# How to increase the height of the selected text's background?

Tags: html, css

I've been looking around Google but can't find a CSS way to increase the height of the background of selected text.

For example the background of the selected text in the Atom editor is noticeably higher than the right one:

[image]

Since Atom is made with HTML/CSS, I wonder if there's a combination of CSS which can achieve this result?

Comment: Have you looked at padding and line-height?

Comment: you can probably try the element:focus property and then set a higher font -size in that becausei think we are just focusing on the content

Comment: @wizzardmr42 Yes, I tried both but the text just goes up and down. The size of the selected text doesn't increase.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the effective css in atom to find it there?

Comment: @wizzardmr42  Yes, and I still can't figure out how they do it, ha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit hacky but you could do it by using a pseudo element (like `::before`) that has a content of non-breaking space and some padding to create the line-height illusion:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}

::selection {
  background: red;
}

p::before {
  content: "\00a0";
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
This is default text

<p>This text has a pseudo element</p>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/8bmj4dm1/

**Caveat:** this will require wrapping each line in a tag. You could probably use JavaScript to automatically wrap each line in a tag for this to work with multi-line content.

Comment: I don't know OP's actual use-case but this would fail if the text spans across multiple lines.

Comment: @Aziz it's hacky, but genius. Thanks!

Comment: @Harry I think it would be alright since each line is a `p` in my app?

Comment: @alexchenco: If you need this only for elements with single line of text then Aziz's answer is excellent and is a very good choice. I am not sure about the question mark at the end, you should know it better :D

Comment: @Harry I'm sure that each line is a `p` tag in my app. I'm just not sure if that will make everything alright.

Comment: If each line is a `p` then it should work @alexchenco.

Comment: If the `::selection` pseudo element accepted `padding` it would be much better. I tried setting an `outline` to `::selection` but it doesn't seem to work even tho MDN reports that it should be supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection